# How do I reference a local svg in React?

Tags: reactjs

The following code compiles just fine but the icon doesn't show up:

[image]

`Icon.jsx` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from 'emotion';

import ArrowRight from "./arrow-right.svg";

export const iconTypes = {
    arrowRight: 'ARROW_RIGHT',
   // arrowLeft: 'ARROW_LEFT',
}

const iconSrc = {
    ARROW_RIGHT: ArrowRight,
   // ARROW_LEFT: ArrowLeft,
}


export default function Icon({ type }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={iconSrc[type]}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

In the browser the request looks like this:

```
 http://localhost:9001/%22data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20version='1.1'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20width='512'%20height='512'%20viewBox='0%200%20512%20512'%3E%20%3Ctitle%3E%3C/title%3E%20%3Cg%20id='icomoon-ignore'%3E%20%3C/g%3E%20%3Cpath%20d='M310.627%20438.627l160-160c12.497-12.496%2012.497-32.758%200-45.255l-160-160c-12.497-12.496-32.758-12.496-45.255%200s-12.497%2032.758%200%2045.255l105.373%20105.373h-306.745c-17.673%200-32%2014.327-32%2032s14.327%2032%2032%2032h306.745l-105.373%20105.373c-6.248%206.248-9.372%2014.438-9.372%2022.627s3.124%2016.379%209.372%2022.627c12.497%2012.497%2032.758%2012.497%2045.255%200z'%3E%3C/path%3E%20%3C/svg%3E%22
```

`Icon.jsx` story:

```
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions"; 
import Icon from "../components/Icon/Index"; 
import { iconTypes } from "../components/Icon/Index";


    storiesOf("Icon", module)
        .add("with text", () => (
            <Icon type={iconTypes.arrowRight}>
            </Icon>
        ));
```

When I fill the `src` with a `http` path (for ex: "https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg") it works just fine.

When I open the svg file directly in the browser it also opens fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

To whoever comes here late as i did, i strongly suggest using [react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg)

A sample code for it:

```
import SvgLogo from './logo.svg';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';

...

render(){
  return(
    <ReactSVG src={SvgLogo} />
  );
}
```

It has all types of customizations required, and great documentations and live examples.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It should be:    import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg';
In case anyone tried to copy this code.

Answer (score 4):

It is much better to use the svg inline rather than as image. It is also easier to parameterise (e.g. the size):

**Icon.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export const iconTypes = {
  arrowRight: 'ARROW_RIGHT',
  arrowLeft: 'ARROW_LEFT',
}

export default function Icon({ type = iconTypes.arrowRight, size = 512 }) {
  return (
    <svg
      width={size}
      height={size}
      viewBox='0 0 512 512'>
      {type === iconTypes.arrowRight &&
        <path d='M310.627 438.627l160-160c12.497-12.496 12.497-32.758 0-45.255l-160-160c-12.497-12.496-32.758-12.496-45.255 0s-12.497 32.758 0 45.255l105.373 105.373h-306.745c-17.673 0-32 14.327-32 32s14.327 32 32 32h306.745l-105.373 105.373c-6.248 6.248-9.372 14.438-9.372 22.627s3.124 16.379 9.372 22.627c12.497 12.497 32.758 12.497 45.255 0z' />
      }
      {type === iconTypes.arrowLeft &&
        <path d="..." />
      }
    </svg>
  )
};
```

*Note: you should leave the `viewBox` prop hardcoded `512` to make the scale work properly.*

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to show default icon in your application is sprite them and use them with their class name. With that, you can cache and have a better performance.

```
<Icon name="plus" size={10} />
```

there are many free tools to sprite your image.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the SVG as a background style on a class and just switch them out depending on what icon you need?

For good performance you can just base64 encode the SVG and paste the contents in a background style in your CSS. http://b64.io/ this is a good site for encoding SVGs

E.g.

```
.kiwi {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94b...");
}
```

Any questions, shout!

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! After trying a few different approaches, this really is the simplest and cleanest solution to bringing SVG's into React

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of webpack `file-loader` options. Add `outputPath` to file-loader option and change `publicPath` to `/` in `output` object.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: { main: ['./ClientApp/boot.jsx'] },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        include: /ClientApp/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties')],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              limit: 8192,
              outputPath: '/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: is the request still the same?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: do you see the file in your dist folder?

Comment: @user3378165 if you are using custom webpack config for storybook then file-loader is the way to add static assets. See here:https://storybook.js.org/configurations/serving-static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure webpack to load inline-svg, in order to do that, install the library `svg-inline-loader` from npm and add the following in your webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       //All the other rules
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Hope this helps.